# Find a branch cut where $f(z)=\log_{\tau}(z^3 - 2)$ is holomorphic at $z=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, branch-cuts

There is a question in my complex analysis textbook whose answer I don't understand, and cannot find a clear explanation online:

> Find a branch cut $C_\tau = \{z=re^{i\tau} : r>0,\tau\in\mathbb{R}\}$ where $f(z)=\log_{\tau}(z^3 - 2)$ is holomorphic at $z=0$

The textbook claims that $f$ is holomorphic only if $-2 \notin C_\tau$.  So any branch cut that is not $(-\infty, 0)$

But to me, it seems like the branch cut should be any cut not containing $z=2^{1/3}e^{2k\pi i /3}$, $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, since that is where $f(z)=\log_\tau (0)$.

Whichever the case, can someone give an end to end explanation??

Answer (score 2):

We are only interested in $z$ close to $0$. If $-2 \notin C_{\tau}$ then $z^{3}-2 \notin C_{\tau}$ for $|z|$ sufficiently small so $f(z)$ is well defined and analytic.

Comment: But if $f: \Omega \subseteq \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$, I thought we only talk about $f'(z)$ when $z$ is an interior point of $\Omega$. Do we still call $f$ analytic at $0$ if it's not even defined on any ball centered at $0$?

Comment: For every $z$ in some disk around $0$, $z^{3}-2$ is not in $C_{\tau}$ so $f(z)$ is well defined and differentiable there.

Comment: Ahhh thank you I was stupid

Comment: Ok i think i got it.  So logarithm is analytic on any branch, which is defined by a branch cut at some angle. So as long as the image is not in the branch cut, it is always holomorphic